# Automatically display `[Char]` as `String` in ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Is there a way to make ghci automatically display all instances of `[Char]` as `String`?  That's what I usually want.

`:set -XOverloadedStrings` does something like what I want, but only for string literals, it seems:

```
Prelude> :type ["foo", "bar"]
["foo", "bar"] :: [[Char]]
Prelude> :set -XOverloadedStrings
Prelude> :type ["foo", "bar"]
["foo", "bar"] :: Data.String.IsString a => [a]
Prelude> f s = "Yes, " ++ s
Prelude> :type f
f :: [Char] -> [Char]
```

I know that I can add `String` to explicit type signatures of every expression that includes `String`/`[Char]` as part of its type, but I prefer to leave most signatures out of my code, even though some authors advise always including type signatures.

(This is likely to be a FAQ, so I won't be surprised if it's closed with a reference to another question, but I have been unable to find that question in my searches.  Those with more experience with Haskell questions in SO may be able to locate previous questions better than I have.)

Comment: `IsString` is not the same as `String`. if you use the `OverloadedStrings` extension, you *generalize* string literals, so now these are no longer only `String`s, but any type that is an instance of `IsString`, so that can be `Text`, `ByteString`, etc.

Comment: IMHO it is better that it uses the signature the functions have used, since although `[Char]` and `String` are the same, it means that the function processes it like a list, not as a `String`, it thus some extra meaning. Furthermore aliasses are sometimes used to later determine a type, and thus easily change between an `type A = Int` and `type A = Float`.

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem.  I knew that `OverloadedStrings` was doing more than what I suggested, but I didn't understand it.  Your clarification is helpful. Anyway, I don't think I want the generalization.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, about it being better to use `[Char]`, I agree for some use cases.  There are tradeoffs.  In my current project, I sometimes struggle to define functions correctly, and I have types that look like this, for example: `[[[Char]]]`.  When I see that, I have to count braces and mentally separate out the `[Char]` from the surrounding braces to figure out whether this is a `[[String]]` or some other embedded list of lists, etc.  One of those is what I should see, and others would represent mistakes in my code.  The type is easier to parse with `String`.  I don't forget it's a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to do that.

Comment: That's a shame.  Well, I shouldn't complain.  At least I have the option of displaying `[Char]` as `String` if I give an explicit signature.

Comment: @Mars And by the way, I expect there will be no way in the future either. It seems hard to automatically replace types by type aliases in a sensible way; for a simple example, what should it do if I define `type DmwitString = [Char]`? A more complex example would be `type Foo a = [Maybe a]; type Bar a = Maybe [a]`; then should `Maybe [Maybe a]` be folded to `Maybe (Foo a)` or `Bar (Maybe a)`? There's no obvious (to me) reason to think one or the other was the clearly intended folding.

Comment: Hmm--interesting examples.  I could imagine `String` being a special case--it already is, in other ways--but then it's probably not worth the trouble for language implementers.